# Is there any difference between hiberfile.sys file and RAM dump made with 3rd party software for Volatility.py?

Tags: windows, forensics, volatility

I was wondering how could I give some advice to one of my friend when attempting to analyze live Windows machine which was infected with malware.

As far as I know, hibernation saves RAM memory contents and compresses them into **hiberfile.sys file**. 
But also there are 3rd party tools like Belkasoft RAM Capturer which read whole RAM and save to file too.

The question is: is there any big difference between those 2 memory dumps? Which one is more "detailed" or "better and more juicy" in terms of forensics?

Comment: a live grab of a known compromised system will always be the better option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When entering hibernation:

1. Apps and services are notified
2. Drivers are notified
3. User and system state is saved to disk in a compressed format
4. Firmware is notified

(Per Microsoft's documenation on [system power states](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/power/system-power-states).)

If an application or rootkit is so designed, it could attempt to hide or clean itself in response to the power state change. There is a timeout period after steps 1 and 2 to allow applications and drivers to prepare for suspension/termination.

This notification is both intentional and necessary: applications/services may span across multiple systems, and drivers must plan for data stored on volatile device memory to be lost. A similar notification occurs prior to system shutdown, albeit with a different status code.

A forensics-oriented tool may avoid "tipping off" the malware in some cases. It is also possible that malware from nation-state actors may detect common forensic tools.

I would expect that moderately sophisticated diskless malware will respond to power state changes, but it may not be capable of detecting forensics tools. So overall, I would expect to see an occasional benefit from using it. I cannot personally speak to the completeness or reliability of that particular tool, however.

Comment: Not to mention the time of each would be different. a hiberfile.sys could be weeks old or longer depending on the system.